# Coefficients of the power series solution for $f'(x)^2+f(x)^4=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

> I am attempting to calculate the power series coefficients of the solution to the differential equation 
>   $$f'(x)^2+f(x)^4=1\qquad f(0)=0.\tag{1}$$

I am trying to do so, because $f(x)$ is the inverse function of $$g(x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^4}},$$
i.e. $f\circ g(x)=g\circ f(x)=x$.
I already know that $f$ can be represented in terms of the Jacobi elliptic function $\mathrm{sn}$ as
$$f(x)=\mathrm{sn}(x|-1),$$
and I was hoping to understand a little more about elliptic functions like this through the lens of power series. I have made a little progress, I think.

First off, let $f'(x)^2=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n$ and $f(x)^4=\sum_{n\ge0}b_nx^n$. Then $$\sum_{n\ge0}(a_n+b_n)x^n=1$$
so $a_0+b_0=1$ and $a_n=-b_n$ for $n>0$. Then let $f(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}f_nx^n$. Our aim is to find $f_n$, or at least evaluate the first few $f_n$. from $(1)$, it's pretty easy to see that $f_0=0$ and $f_1=1$. Then we see, from the Cauchy product,
$$f'(x)^2=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)(n-k+1)f_{k+1}f_{n-k+1}$$
and 
$$f(x)^4=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}q_kq_{n-k}$$
where $$q_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}f_rf_{n-r}.$$
Thus for $n>0$, $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(q_kq_{n-k}+(k+1)(n-k+1)f_{k+1}f_{n-k+1}\right)=0.$$
Is there an easier way to calculate these coefficients?

Comment: Please read [OEIS sequence A104203](https://oeis.org/A104203) expansion coefficients of sine lemniscate function.

Comment: The theory of elliptic functions is complicated, follow a textbook, for now don't try to create examples and problems yourself. Elliptic function $\implies$ meromorphic on the compact Riemann surface $\Bbb{C}/L \implies $ defined by its poles (a doubly periodic function with no pole is entire and bounded thus constant). There is no point to search for the expansion in $z$ of doubly periodic function, we look instead at the Fourier expansion in $e^{2i\pi \omega z}$. You can find the periods by integrating $\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^4}}$ over the closed-loops around $1,i,-1,-i$.

Comment: The Taylor series for elliptic do not follow any pattern. A more useful approach is to learn about their Fourier series and infinite product representations.

Comment: The function (lemniscatic function as they arise while finding the arc length of a lemniscate) in your question was studied in great detail by Abel (on the suggestion of Gauss in *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*). And Abel got some glimpse into the theory of complex multiplication and deduced the theorem regarding dissection of lemniscate into equal parts.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Again, you seem to know a lot of amazing stuff. Would you mind adding this in an answer? Thanks.

Comment: The details of Abel's investigation are presented beautifully by David Cox in his *Galois Theory* (see chapter 15). For infinite series and product representations of elliptic functions it is best that you start their study systematically using the references I gave earlier or through my blog posts. The topic is difficult and a simple answer here won't do justice. Here is another tip: most references about elliptic functions which I gave are freely available online if you search properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential generating function of [OEIS sequence A104203](https://oeis.org/A104203)
is your $\,f(x).\,$ This function is known as the Gauss
[lemniscate sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscatic_elliptic_function).
It satisfies the differential equations
$$ f\,'(x)^2 + f(x)^4 = 1 \quad \text{ and }\quad f''(x) = -2f(x)^3. $$
The second differential equation implies that the sequence satisfies the recursion
$$ a_{n+2} = -2 \sum_{i+j+k = n} \frac{n!}{i!\,j!\,k!}\,a_i\,a_j\,a_k $$
The first few terms are
$$ a_2 = -2\,a_0^3,\;\; a_3 = -6\,a_0^2a_1,\;\; a_4 = 12\,a_0(a_0^4-a_1^2),\;\;
  a_5 = -12\,a_1(-9\,a_0^4+a_1^2). $$
When $\,a_0=0,\,a_1=1,\,$  we get the sequence $\,A104203:
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -12, 0, 0, 0,3024,\dots.$

Comment: I gather then that the expectation of a closed form is unrealistic. Thanks!